# Calling a specific column in a subset of data that has been binned and stored in a list

Tags: r

I have a very large data set that I have binned, and stored each bin (subset) as a list so that I can easily call any given subset. My problem is in calling for a specific column within a subset.

For example my data (which has diameters and strengths as the columns), is broken up into 20 bins, by diameter. I manually binned the data, like so:

```
subset.1 <- subset(mydata, Diameter <= 0.01)
```

Similar commands were used, to make 20 bins. Then I stored the names (subset.1 through subset.20) into a list:

```
diameter.bin<-list(subset.1, ... , subset.20)
```

I can successfully call each diameter bin using:

```
diameter.bin[x]
```

Now, if I only want to see the strength values for a given diameter bin, I can use the original name (that is store in the list):

```
subset.x$Strength
```

But I cannot get this information using the list call:

```
diameter.bin[x]$Strength
```

This command returns `NULL`

Note that when I call any subset (either by `diameter.bin[x]`, `subset.x` or even `subset.x$Strength`) my column headers do show up. When I use:

```
names(subset.1)
```

This returns `"Diameter"` and `"Strength"`

But when I use:

```
names(diameter.bin[1])
```

This returns `NULL`.

I'm assuming that the column header is part of the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it, other than take the headers off of the original data file. I would prefer not to do this if at all possible.

The end goal is to look at the distribution of strength values for each diameter bin, so I will be doing things like drawing histograms, calculating parameters etc. I was hoping to do something along these lines to produce the histograms:

```
n=length(diameter.bin)
for(i in (1:n))
{
  hist(diameter.bin[i]$Strength)
}
```

And do something similar to this to store median values for each bin in a new vector.

Any tips are greatly appreciated, as right now I'm doing it all 1 bin at a time, and I know a loop (or something similar) would really speed up my analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two square brackets.  Here is a reproducible example demonstrating the issue:

```
> diam <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5))
> 
> diam.l <- list(diam, diam)
> diam.l[1]$x
NULL
> diam.l[[1]]$x
[1] -0.5389441 -0.5155441 -1.2437108 -2.0044323 -0.6914124
```